# best practices for designing a page with lots of events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a grid on a page that displays tablular data, with a checkbox by each row.

So in this situation, when a checkbox is clicked, allot of things will react on the page potentially.

Also, if a button is clicked, again allot of things will potentially react on the page.

So say if someone checks a checkbox, the row should be highlighted, there is a toolbar that will show/hide buttons, etc.

If someone were to click on the toolbar directly, again things similar to when the checkbox was clicked will react.

So what I want to do is this, whenever a checkbox is clicked, or whenever a toolbar button is clicked, I want to 'announce' to anyone who is listening that this event occurred.

I can then, based on the source of the event, react in a similar or different manner.

how to best go about designing things like this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to look into using the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  Basically, interested parties subscribe or listen for an event on a publisher, and when the event occurs, the source notifies all the listeners of it.

Comment: +1 for promoting a pattern. Although in JQuery it's kinda tricky to use Classes. That's why i like Mootools =)

Answer (score 1):

two things come to mind:
1. event delegation (you don't want to bind to each input on the grid)
look at this link to a great way of doing this while also maintaining a clean code:
by [ben nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2034-Using-Composed-Javascript-UI-Controllers-With-Event-Delegation.htm)
2. using custom events, or even better - [use this pub/sub plugin](http://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/pubsub.js)

i have a large grid like this in my app that evolved over time, and manually binding to each input + responding in different ways caused the code to be a "bit" ugly,
It's great that you now where you are going and prepare up front

Answer (score 0):

You could try [YUI Custom Events](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/event/custom-event.html). This allow you to fire off your own "event" which listeners can hear.

Comment: I believe jquery also does custom events.

Answer (score 0):

I like how it works with jquery, since you can bind an event to many 
elements at once.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(e){
    alert(e.currentTarget.id);    
    });
```

This code would make all checkboxes alert their name. Of course, by using css classes, 
you could bind a subset of all checkboxes to create an action.

```
$("input[type=checkbox].cssClass").click(function(e){    
    someOtherFunction(e.currentTarget);
    });
```